# How can I pass one of group variables value as a template parameter?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've got yaml pipeline that referes some templates.
I have variable group linked to this main yaml file and I want to pass one of its variables to the template.

It's simple when I want to "just use it" as bellow:

example:

```
stages:
  - stage: Deployment
    variables:
    - group: My_group_variables
    jobs:
      - template: /templates/jobs/myJobTemplate.yml
        parameters:
          someParameter: $(variable_from_my_variable_group)
```

myJobTemplate.yml:

```
parameters:
  - name: someParameter
    default: ''

jobs:
  - job: Myjob
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: cat ${{ parameters.someParameter}}
```

It does not cooperate when I want to have parameters validation like:

```
parameters:
  - name: environmentName
    type: string
    values:
    - Development
    - Test
    - UAT
    - Production
```

Or when I want to use "service connection" name as a variable.

```
...
    - task: KubernetesManifest@0
      displayName: Deploy to Kubernetes cluster
      inputs:
        action: 'deploy'
        kubernetesServiceConnection: ${{ parameters.kubernetesServiceConnection }}
        namespace: ${{ parameters.kubernetesNamespace }}
        manifests: ${{ variables.manifestFile }}
...
```

Does anyone know how should I use those variables with pre-validated parameters or service connections?

It's most probably an issue with the time of resolving values. Pre-defined parameters and service connections names are checked on compile-time, while values from $() are resolved during runtime.

I cannot use extends and variables in this template.

Maybe someone has a pattern for those kinds of usage?

Comment: When you say "it does not cooperate", what do you mean? does the pipeline or template not compile? Do you get a specific error message? Does nothing happen? Providing a larger sample from your pipeline and template might be helpful.

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole I mean that it cannot see the value. It treats the name as a value and prints the error that this Environment/Service Connection does not exist.